# POST http://localhost:16/auth/registration/ 400 (Bad Request) in Django and Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, django

I am making a registration in django and reactjs project, i use django rest auth for registration api, but i am having a problem, when i send request to server, it responses:

> POST http://localhost:16/auth/registration/ 400 (Bad Request)

I don't know how to fix this, can anyone help me ?

this is my code !

**Register.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

class Register extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            username: '',
            email: '',
            password1: '',
            password2: '',
        }
        this.OnChangeUsername = this.OnChangeUsername.bind(this)
        this.OnChangeEmail = this.OnChangeEmail.bind(this) 
        this.OnChangePassword1 = this.OnChangePassword1.bind(this)
        this.OnChangePassword2 = this.OnChangePassword2.bind(this)
        this.OnSubmit = this.OnSubmit.bind(this)
    }

    OnChangeUsername(event) {
        this.setState({
            username: event.target.value
        })
    }

    OnChangeEmail(event) {
        this.setState({
            email: event.target.value
        })
    }

    OnChangePassword1(event) {
        this.setState({
            password1: event.target.value
        })
    }

    OnChangePassword2(event) {
        this.setState({
            password2: event.target.value
        })
    }

    OnSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        axios.post('http://localhost:16/auth/registration/', {
            username: this.state.username,
            email: this.state.email,
            password1: this.state.password1,
            password2: this.state.password2,
        })
        .then(res => {
            alert('Registered !')
            this.props.history.push('/')
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.OnSubmit}>
                    <input type="text" name="username" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.OnChangeUsername} />
                    <br></br>
                    <input type="text" name="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.OnChangeEmail} />
                    <br></br>
                    <input type="text" name="password1" value={this.state.password1} onChange={this.OnChangePassword1} />
                    <br></br>
                    <input type="text" name="password2" value={this.state.password2} onChange={this.OnChangePassword2} />
                    <br></br>
                    <button>Register</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Register;
```

Comment: Have you tried posting using browsable API provided with DRF. It is working there (if not the issue is with django code else in react).

Comment: Can you give me some links ?

Comment: `http://localhost:16/auth/registration/` go to this link in browser itself and try to make a POST request and check whether data gets posted or not. If not then isssue is with Django API,